# WIll my Activity Context remain not null after the Android app is terminated?

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-service, android-context, android-lifecycle

I have activity A, that is used as a context in vpnService B and class C.
vpnService B has a thread that starts when the VPN starts. Because of this, after the application is terminated it keeps running. My question is, will the context from A, still be able to be accessed on whenever B and C want to access it? Would I have to bind the context itself to the service to retain the values? I have provided a sample in code format to further explain my question.

Also, B extends vpnService. So when the VPN is disabled either programmatically or by being disabled by the user it still goes through the onDestroy()

```
public class A extend Activity(){
    private static aContext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_A);

        aContext = A.this;

        //vpn service starts
        //assume that the user alerts to allow it have already been implemented
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
        startService(myIntent);
    }

    static Context getContext() {
        return aContext;
    }
}

/**
* Would I still be able to access the context from A on B and C after the application ends?
* i.e. when the user dismisses it from the app drawer?
*/

public class B extends vpnService {
    private ScheduledExecutorService ex;
    private static C cRef;

    Runnable aThread = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            C.doStuff();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  
        ex = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        //new thread every second
        ex.scheduleAtFixedRate(aThread, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

     @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        //shutd down the executor
        ex.shutdownNow();
    }
}

public class C{
    public void doStuff(){
        A.getContext();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think no. Such architecture seems totally weird. There is a lot places where you can face memory leaks.
It's totaly wrong put such types as Context, Activity, Fragment in static scope.
You should revise your task and change architecture.

Btw, if you need Context in C.class, you can getContext() from your Service nor-Activity.

Hope this help you.